# what framework should i use for this game?

Tags: iphone, frameworks

hi all
i'm beginner to iOS
i'm trying to make a game when i use NSTimer for action a Ball (for example)
and use CGPointMake for posing in the view its so unreal i mean its like an 
old pc with low ram (frame frame) i thought i need to use a Framework for THIS
Can any body help me?

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration{

xValue = acceleration.x*80.0;
yValue = acceleration.y*80.0;

ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + xValue, ball.center.y);

if (ball.center.x < 24.0) {
    ball.center = CGPointMake(24.0 , ball.center.y);
}
if (ball.center.x > 296.0) {
    ball.center = CGPointMake(296.0 , ball.center.y);
}
}
```

Comment: Post your code.  You're likely doing things wrong as there are many high performing applications written using NSTimer.

Comment: Sorry, but your question doesn't make much (if indeed any) sense. I think you need to take the time to properly explain your problem.

Comment: Also, without your code we can't even guess what your problem might be as the question is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely go for cocos2d and Box2D for your physics:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/

http://www.box2d.org/

There are plenty of tutorials out there on both.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question.

OpenGL is a good framework to use for game creation, especially graphics rendering on iOS devices.

[Here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html) is a good tutorial you might like to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

http://www.iphonedevbook.com/

If you register on the forum, you can download the sample code from the book "Beginning iPhone 3 Development".
Chapter 15 is called "Ball", and has code which rolls a ball around the screen, based on input from the accelerometer.

Answer (score 1):

cocos2d is a nice framework for writing iPhone games

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/